# How to change the text size of a checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

It looks like this.
[image]

I want to change the *text size* of a `checkbox` in a fragment. 
The text size itself became bigger, but the little field of the `checkbox` is now a little bit higher than the text.
I hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks

This is my code for the `CheckBox`:

```
<CheckBox
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:text="Text"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/my_padding"
        android:id="@+id/text" />
```

Comment: captain america upz java can you add image of your output and full xml ?

Comment: You can to set a drawable as CheckBox background `android:background="@drawable/my_checkbox"` as your size preference

Comment: Remove `android:paddingTop` and check.

Comment: @captain java are you still facing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
<CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Text"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
```

Comment: I'm currently using a LinearLayout. All the other views are adjusted for the LinearLayout, so I don't want to change to a RelativeLayout.

Comment: I updated my code plz try with that thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Simply set the `textAppearance` attribute to your desired value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckBox
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Subtitle1" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to scale it as you need

**P.S** check at run time

If you got a problem with text size when you scaling
use 
this

`checkBox.TextSize = (int)(TEXT_SIZE/SCALE_FACTOR);`

```
<CheckBox
    ...
    android:scaleX="0.60"
    android:scaleY="0.60"
/>
```

Comment: This is not working. The box is still a little bit higher than the text

Comment: @captain java try to adjust sizes use my text size scale code, you can adjust them